# Almost everywhere agreement (Hyperreals)

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

Let F be a non-principal ultrafilter and let ~ denote the equivalence relation r~s iff {n belongs to natural numbers: r_n=s_n} belongs to F. I.E. the sets of indexes on which the r and s agree is in F.

I'm trying to then show that <1,1/2,1/3,...> is not equal to <0,0,0,...>. I know they aren't as clearly they have no indexes in common, but not too sure how to show this... Can I just show that there intersection is the empty set? (not sure how to though). PS sorry for no Latex, couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 3):

The two elements are different if they are not equivalent. They are indeed not equivalent since if they were equivalent, then, by definition of $\sim$, the set of indices where the two agree would be in $F$. As you say, the set of indices where they agree is empty, and the empty set is never an element of a non-principal filter (since if the empty set is an element in a filter $F$ on some set $X$, then since any subset $S\subseteq X$ satisfies $S\supseteq \emptyset$, it would follow that $S\in F$, and thus $F=\mathcal P (X)$, not a principal filter).